# One-sided ideals in $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

It is well known that $K(H)$, the set of compact operators on a separable Hilbert space $H$ is the only two-sided closed ideal in $B(H)$, the algebra of all bounded linear operators.

Ar there any closed *one-sided* ideal in $B(H)$ other than $K(H)$? In fact, can anyone give me an example of a one-sided but not two-sided ideal in $B(H)$, not necessarily closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $K\subset H$ is a subspace, then $\{T\in B(H)\mid T(H)\subset K\}$ is a right-sided ideal. It is closed if $K$ is a closed subspace. Similarly you get left-sided ideals by considering all operators whose kernel contains a given subspace. Except for the trivial cases, these are no two-sided ideals.

Comment: Are all one-sided ideals of $\mathcal{B}(H)$ of these two types? It seems to me they should. But don't know how to prove.

Comment: No. For example, something like $\{T\in K(H)\mid T(H)\subset K\}$ should also give you a closed right ideal. But every *weak$^\ast$* closed right ideal is of this form by ideal theory in von Neumann algebras.

Comment: By $K(H)$, do you mean compact operators? What's $K$ in $T(H)\subset K$, in this context?

Comment: Oh yes, I see how that's confusing. Yes, $K(H)$ are the compact operators and the second $K$ is a fixed closed subspace of $H$. If $K$ is infinite-dimensional, then this ideal I described in the previous comment is strictly contained in the one from the answer.